# Kubernetes getting cluster locks over a replication

Tags: kubernetes

I have an application running in a Kubernetes pod that is replicated using a replication controller. However I need to some critical tasks that should be done by a single application (one replication) at a time. Previously I used zookeeper to get a cluster lock to do that task. Is there a way in Kubernetes to get a cluster lock for a particular replication controller?

Answer (score 7):

Kubernetes doesn't have a cluster lock object, but you can use an [annotation](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/annotations.html) on the replication controller to specify the lock holder and TTL.

For example, each pod could read the the annotation key `"lock"`, and if empty (or if TTL expired), try to write `"lock": "pod-xyz: 2015-12-22T18:39:12+00:00"`. If multiple writes are attempted, kubernetes will accept one, and reject the others w/ a 409 because the resource version will not be correct. The lock holder would then continue updating the annotation to refresh the TTL.

If you have a service that corresponds to this replication controller, it might make sense to put the lock annotation on the service instead of the RC. Then the locking semantics would survive software upgrades (e.g. rolling-update). The annotation can go on any object, so there's some flexibility to figure out what works best for you.

[podmaster.go](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/pod-master/podmaster.go#L49) had a good example of the logic you might use to implement this. It is running directly against etcd, which you could also do if you don't mind introducing another component.

Comment: How should the application in the pod write/ read annotation to the service? Is it through the REST API?

Comment: Yeah. The client libraries should have what you need if you don't want to craft raw requests. It might be possible through kubectl as well. I'm not sure.

Comment: Isn't that a good idea to use etcd native cluster lock support and expose it over a kubernetes API? https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/0.4.7/etcd-api/#lock

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the clocks on different nodes are synchronized?  That's a pretty tough assumption.

Answer (score 1):

2021 Update: Kubernetes now has built-in in support for leader election lock.

Official sample can be found here: [Java](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/examples/examples-release-12/src/main/java/io/kubernetes/client/examples/LeaderElectionExample.java) and [Go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/leader-election/main.go). Main piece of code that uses this API may look like this:

```
// start the leader election code loop
leaderelection.RunOrDie(ctx, leaderelection.LeaderElectionConfig{
    Lock: lock,
    ReleaseOnCancel: true,
    LeaseDuration:   60 * time.Second,
    RenewDeadline:   15 * time.Second,
    RetryPeriod:     5 * time.Second,
    Callbacks: leaderelection.LeaderCallbacks{
        OnStartedLeading: func(ctx context.Context) {
            // we're notified when we start - this is where you would
            // usually put your code
            run(ctx)
        },
        OnStoppedLeading: func() {
            // we can do cleanup here
            klog.Infof("leader lost: %s", id)
            os.Exit(0)
        },
        OnNewLeader: func(identity string) {
            // we're notified when new leader elected
            if identity == id {
                // I just got the lock
                return
            }
            klog.Infof("new leader elected: %s", identity)
        },
    },
})
```